# Nested promises not resolving properly, only returning promise when using decomposed promise handlers

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

There are similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45409078/javascript-promise-not-working-with-resolve), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37562011/promise-not-resolving-as-expected), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49728901/es6-promise-are-sometimes-not-resolving), but none help.

We have nested promises, but they aren't resolving. Instead of returning data from the innermost promise, the outermost promise returns a promise.

The goal is to decompose promise handlers into separate functions as illustrated below (e.g., `requestDidSucceed`, `requestDidFail`).

How can we do this while ensuring the outermost promise returns properly?

**Codepen**

https://codepen.io/Crashalot/pen/0ba95ebb26d0f68fb95ea065ef6af3dd?editors=0002

**Code**

```
class TestClass {
    translate() {
        // Create promise.
        let promise = $.Deferred();     

        let bm = new BatchManagerClass();

        bm.translate()
        .then( successResult => requestDidSucceed(promise, successResult) )
        .catch( errorResult => requestDidFail(promise, errorResult) );

        // Return promise.
        return promise;
    }

  
    requestDidSucceed(promise, successResult) {
        promise.resolve(successResult);
    }


    requestDidFail(promise, errorResult) {
        promise.reject(errorResult);
    }
}


class BatchManagerClass {
    translate() {
        // Create promise.
        let promise = $.Deferred();     

        let test = new ServiceClass();

        test.makeRequest()
        .then( successResult => requestDidSucceed(promise, successResult) )
        .catch( errorResult => requestDidFail(promise, errorResult) );

        // Return promise.
        return promise;
    }
    

     requestDidSucceed(promise, successResult) {
        promise.resolve(successResult);
     }


     requestDidFail(promise, errorResult) {
        promise.reject(errorResult);
     }
}


class ServiceClass {
    makeRequest() {
       let promise = $.Deferred();      

       promise.resolve('This works');

       return promise;
    }  
}


let test = new TestClass();

test.translate()
  .then( successResult => requestDidSucceed(successResult) )
  .catch( errorResult => requestDidFail(errorResult) );


function requestDidSucceed(successResult) {
  console.log('Success result: ' + successResult);
}


function requestDidFail(errorResult) {
  console.log('Failure result: ' + errorResult);
}
```

Comment: one question, why didnt you use `this.requestDidSucceed` inside the classes?

Comment: `bm.translate()
        .then( successResult => requestDidSucceed(promise, successResult) )
        .catch( errorResult => requestDidFail(promise, errorResult) );` - this will not call its method but the global `requestDidSucceed(successReult)` function.

Comment: @yash because that was the bug. :) thanks for your help!

Comment: sorry but which email do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling a method of a class, `this.` must be added like `this.requestDidSucceed()`.

```
class TestClass {
    translate() {
        // Create promise.
        let promise = $.Deferred();     

        let bm = new BatchManagerClass();

        bm.translate()
        .then( successResult => this.requestDidSucceed(promise, successResult) )
        .catch( errorResult => this.requestDidFail(promise, errorResult) );

        // Return promise.
        return promise;
    }

  
    requestDidSucceed(promise, successResult) {
        promise.resolve(successResult);
    }


    requestDidFail(promise, errorResult) {
        promise.reject(errorResult);
    }
}


class BatchManagerClass {
    translate() {
        // Create promise.
        let promise = $.Deferred();     

        let test = new ServiceClass();

        test.makeRequest()
        .then( successResult => this.requestDidSucceed(promise, successResult) )
        .catch( errorResult => this.requestDidFail(promise, errorResult) );

        // Return promise.
        return promise;
    }
    

     requestDidSucceed(promise, successResult) {
        promise.resolve(successResult);
     }


     requestDidFail(promise, errorResult) {
        promise.reject(errorResult);
     }
}


class ServiceClass {
    makeRequest() {
       let promise = $.Deferred();      

       promise.resolve('This works');

       return promise;
    }  
}


let test = new TestClass();

test.translate()
  .then( successResult => requestDidSucceed(successResult) )
  .catch( errorResult => requestDidFail(errorResult) );


function requestDidSucceed(successResult) {
  console.log('Success result: ' + successResult);
}


function requestDidFail(errorResult) {
  console.log('Failure result: ' + errorResult);
}
```